# css determine single and multiple images in one container

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm currently building a blog and have an image container for each blog post, as you do, which may only contain one or may contain multiple images.

I've been googling for a while to try and find a css only solution to handling my scenario:

if i have one image it stretches to 100% width or height keeping aspect, easily solved with the usual fix, incidentally all that google returns:

```
#img-container{ overflow:hidden }
#img-container img{ 
   width:auto; 
   height:auto; 
   max-width:100%; 
   max-height:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

if i have multiple images they are placed in a grid like formation of up to 3 images per row at around a third or half container width (depending on amount).

I know i could do some php count and individual classes but would rather an all css solution.

I have read about flex-box but have little experience/knowledge of this but from what i have heard i believe this may be the answer??

any help greatly appreciated, and if you feel there is no css only solution to dynamic amount of images please do say and i will revert to (js || php) && css

thanks

also this should be as cross browser compatible as possible but then i guess this is expected by most.

Comment: CSS can't detect content only style it. If you could create a small demo of the issue it's possible that we might find a creative solution but at the moment it's a little hard to visualise the issue.

Comment: CSS can't answer conditional statements, you would either have to use Javascript/JQuery for this, or look into using SASS, which I believe allows for conditional operators to be used.

Comment: Thanks, i do understand regarding conditionals in css. your demo Paulie_D is literally what i am doing - a div container filled with a dynamic amount of images. looks like both the answers would be relevant; will give them a try and select an answer after testing. much appreciated guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick based on nth-last child that will work here.

[**Lea Verou reference link**](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/) which references this [**original link**](http://andr3.net/blog/post/142)

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
float: left;
}

img:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}
/* two items */
img:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2), 
img:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 50%;
}
/* three items */
img:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3), 
img:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2), 
img:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/3/" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good and exactly what i was after. I did change it a little so that the image was never resized greater than its original dimensions, i just added `width:auto` and changed `width:100%` to `max-width:100%` etc

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative Paulie_D's example using `flexbox` and a different `:nth-child` approach.

It allows any number of elements but never more than three per row. If there are more than three elements the width of all will be restricted to 1/3 of the parent element which I think is what you were asking for in your question.

It does however rely on an element wrapped around each `img`...

```css
hr {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 33.33%;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(3n+4),
.wrap div:nth-child(3n+5){
    width: 33.33%;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.wrap div img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Seven items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Six items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
<hr> 
<h3>Five items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
<hr> 
<h3>Four items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
<hr> 
<h3>Three items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Two items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
<hr>   
<h3>One items</h3>
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
```

There are some inconstancies with flexbox implementation between browsers so [mixing old and new syntax may be required (more info)](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/hpop0bw6/)

Comment: Thanks for the alternate and the resource on cross browser, I will test Paulie_D's first though as that looks a little more cross browser friendly, but please do correct me if i am wrong.